# Difference between GNU tar's --transform and --xform options

Tags: filenames, tar, options

What is the main difference between GNU `tar` `--transform` to `--xform`?

From reading the [GNU tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#IDX184), I assume they might be the same and the latter is a "sugar syntax".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent and you can quickly check that. With `--xform`:

```
$ tar -cf archive.tar FILE
$ tar -xf archive.tar --xform='s,F,m,'
$ ls -Al
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users     0 Aug 19 14:09 FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 10240 Aug 19 14:09 archive.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users     0 Aug 19 14:09 mILE
```

And with `--transform`:

```
$ touch FILE
$ tar -cf archive.tar FILE
$ tar -xf archive.tar --transform='s,F,m,'
$ ls -Al
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users     0 Aug 19 14:09 FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 10240 Aug 19 14:09 archive.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users     0 Aug 19 14:09 mILE
```

If you haven't already, please notice that you don't have to look up for documentation online as your Linux system should come with a set of manpages;
for example, executing `man tar`.

In case of similar questions consult `man man-pages` that describe
`conventions for writing Linux man pages` although it does not
describe this particular `option=xxx, equivalent-option=xxx` syntax.

And finally, GNU people do not like manpges and prefer `info`.

Comment: ... and this equivalence is explicitly listed in `tar`’s manpage.

Comment: Yes, although it may be unclear for those who have never read any manpages although it becomes clear naturally for those who have.

Comment: I read man pages many times in my life but I didn't think I should read `man tar` after I read in the online GNU manual - which I should have done.

Comment: The problem with online manuals is that they do not always describe the version of program you have installed locally therefore I prefer reading manpage first.